# embeded script iframe in wordpress not showing except to logged on user

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I am writing following code in post. But the chart widget is showing to me only(admin) not to visitor.

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_c80ea"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "in",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_c80ea"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Have you [registered the script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) to be enqueued by WordPress?

Comment: Thanks teleod for reply. But I don't know which code to be registered in function file. Can you provide the solution using above example?